# "Firebase App Distribution Admin" role is missing

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-app-distribution

I'm struggling to configure the firebase app distribution to deploy my android application. But I'm receiving the following error:

> App Distribution halted because it had a problem uploading the APK:
> [403] The caller does not have permission

It pretty sure that the problem resides in the step where I need to include the **Firebase App Distribution Admin** role through the Google Cloud console:

[image]

But, the *** role doesn't appear when I try to include it:

[image]

I tried to include the Firebase App Distribution Admin SDK Service agent but I received the error described at the beginning. Any advice will be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well... I fixed the problem, creating from scratch a new account

Answer (score 0):

[Firebase App Distribution roles](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles-predefined-product#app-distro) lists role `roles/firebaseappdistro.admin`.